# rowcount before and after query

Tags: sql, t-sql

Can someone explain the difference between these 2 simple queries ...

```
SET ROWCOUNT = 10
select * from t_Account order by account_date_last_maintenance
```

and this one

```
select * from t_Account order by account_date_last_maintenance
SET ROWCOUNT = 10
```

when executed both return only 10 rows, but the rows are different. There are millions of rows in the table if that matters.  Also, the first query runs consistently 20% longer.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute SET ROWCOUNT 10 you are telling SQL to stop the query after 10 results are returned.  Your first SQL statement is the correct syntax (with the exception of the first line which should read SET ROWCOUNT 10).

The second statement as written will return all of the values ordered when initially executed and then set the row count to 10, so any subsequent execution will return the first 10 items.

ROWCOUNT must be set to 0 to get things back to "normal" execution.

As to why things were returning differently, the data might not be processed the same every time and given the size of your dataset it is most likely that you might sometimes get matching results, but it is not a sure thing. If you want consistent results and only want the first 10 results I would recommend using TOP.

Comment: you're right about the syntax, sorry I typed it in here hastily and added the =.  As for the results, I might be misunderstanding but it seems like you are saying that if I execute that second statement I will get > 10 rows the first time, and only 10 the second.  That is not what I see, when I execute the second statement, I only get 10 rows in my result set the first time I run it.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Try this.  Type SET ROWCOUNT 0  Then copy and paste your 2nd statement and execute. It should return more than 10 rows.  Then run just your 2nd statement again and you should only get 10 rows back.  SET ROWCOUNT gets rememebered and you need to disable it once its turned on.

Comment: I did what you suggested and it worked like you said.  I guess it just had a 'hold' of that other value when i was testing and confusing me.  Thanks for the explanation.